# Windows service not getting uninstalled

Tags: c#, windows-services, command-prompt

I want to uninstall Windows Service from command prompt but that is not working getting below error

> 'installutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

This way I have tried command

```
D:\backup\WindowsService\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\obj\Debug>installutil -u TestService.exe

D:\backup\WindowsService\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\obj\Debug>installutil -u "TestService.exe"
```

How can I uninstall service?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? It's not clear.

Comment: @Ali1928 - Error I have mentioned very first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your comment, your issue seems related to %PATH%.

There is no such thing as "installutil" on your Windows. I believe "installutil" has created by you right?

Let's assume that binary resides at C:\Myproject\installutil.exe

There are two ways to execute it.

**First:**

C:\users\username> cd C:\Myproject
C:\Myproject> .\installutil.exe -u "bla bla bla bla".

**Second:**

Go to your start menu and search for "environment". Open "Edit the system variables" under "System properties". At the "Advanced" tab, you'll see "Environment Variables". You'll see a variable named "Path". Edit it's value and add your own .exe path at the end.

When you execute "echo %PATH" at command prompt, you should see your binary's folder. Otherwise, command prompt will not be able to find it.

**EDIT:**

**So yeah, there is one such thing called installutil.exe and it can be used by the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio.**

Command to uninstall service: `installutil -u "AirwatchService.exe"`

Are you sure you're using the right command prompt? Do you have the absolute path of this binary?

Please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/installutil-exe-installer-tool

Comment: When I installed the .exe, that time same command `installutil` worked.

Comment: What was your current working directory while you've been able to execute "installutil" and what is it now? "When I installed the .exe", which exe? TestUtil.exe?

Comment: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil "D:\backup\WindowsService\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\obj\Debug\TestService.exe"` this worked for me at the time of installing TestService.exe but at the time of uninstalling it is not working.